# Doing a LIKE and a BETWEEN on the same column

Tags: php, html, mysql, search

I'm trying to make an online searchable database. I want the user to be able to search for all entries by year, so if they want a specific year, there is a search box for that. If they want to input a range of years, I put two search boxes for that, which map to the variables "startyear" and "endyear." Here is my code in my php file:

```
<?php
$year=$_GET['year'];
$startyear=$_GET['startyear'];
$endyear=$_GET['endyear'];                    
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE year(date_on_ledger) LIKE '%$year%' AND year(date_on_ledger) BETWEEN '%$startyear%' AND '%$endyear%' ");
```

This doesn't work, when I try putting in a start and end year, it gives me no results. I think it's because of the AND (it's trying to find years between start and endyear, that also match the normal year entry being empty). How should I go about fixing this so I can have both search options? Thanks!

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: What format is the `year` column?

Comment: Try using OR instead of AND. Also, try removing the percentage from the $startyear and $endyear.

Comment: I will look into PDO's, though I would like to figure out why this isn't working regardless, as it seems like a very basic idea. The year column stores everything as strings I believe. I tried removing the percent signs and using OR but that just made it output every entry in the database.

Comment: Also, when I leave only the BETWEEN statement and take out the LIKE statement, it works fine. Similarly, having only the LIKE statement works fine. But when they're together, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OR instead of AND.

Comment: When I do "$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE year(date_on_ledger) LIKE '%$year%' OR year(date_on_ledger) BETWEEN '%$startyear%' AND '%$endyear%' ");", it brings up every entry in the database. I think this is because it's matching everything that either contains "" or is between start and end year, and every entry contains "".